# How to remove extra wrappers for CollectionView with MarionetteJS?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am having a similar problem as was discussed here for a LayoutView, i.e. that extra wrappers are created: [Extra wrappers in Backbone and Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195242/extra-wrappers-in-backbone-and-marionette)

Now, I am trying to use a CollectionView and see similarly that some unexpected `div` appear.

My CollectionView looks like:

```
MA.Views.Composites.Movies = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  template: 'composites/movies',

});

MA.addInitializer(function(){
  MA.collections.movies = new MA.Collections.Movies();
  MA.composites.movies = new MA.Views.Composites.Movies({
    itemView: MA.Views.Items.Movie,
    collection: MA.collections.movies
  });
  MA.collections.movies.fetch();
});
```

The template:

```
 <div id="movies">
   movies
 </div>
```

The ItemView:

```
MA.Views.Items.Movie = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: 'items/movie',

  views: {}
});
```

and ItemView template:

```
<div class="item">
  {{ title }}
</div>
```

The resulting HTML looks like:

[image: extra wrappers]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that I mixed CompositeView with CollectionView. By adding `className` properties on the views, the solution quickly becomes visible. The ItemView should not contain a wrapping `div` in the template, as this is added by the ItemView.